# How to install windows 10 in HDD while Ubuntu is running in SSD?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I am using ASUS FX553VD laptop with ~256GB SSD and 1 TB HDD. In SSD Ubuntu 18.04 is running. and that HDD is free.

So, I want to install Windows 10 in HDD. Is it possible ? And if it is, then should I remove my SSD first while installing Winows 10 ?

Fine. Suppose I did as I mention. Now I installed my SSD again. So,

1. what will happens while on boot ? Which OS will running fine ?
2. If I want to run both OS smoothly then what are the ways or steps I should follow during installation of windows.

Actually I want to play some games on windows during this lockdown period.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Comment: Is system UEFI or older BIOS(upgrade from Windows 7)? Is Ubuntu installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. You want Windows in same boot mode, but if UEFI system better to have both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. You may not have to physically disconnect SSD, but in UEFI set drive to disabled. You may have to use efibootmgr to restore Ubuntu entry in UEFI. But if drive is on, Windows will normally install to default boot drive in UEFI, which may overwrite Ubuntu. Best to have good backups.

Comment: @karel Partially maybe YES. But see, what I want to do... I want to install both OS in separate physical device. And want to access it like as normal boot - via Grub Options. Ubuntu must boot as a default OS, but window os should install in secondary  HDD.

Comment: @oldfred Yes, my Ubuntu 18.04 install in SSD with UEFI enable mode. I want to install both OS in separate physical device(SSD and HDD). As you say, when Windows 10 will installed it will erase entry for Ubuntu, I agree with that. 

So, the batter and easy way is First install windows 10 in HDD then Install Ubuntu in SSD, this way maybe I can  access both OS from Ubuntu Grub.

Comment: That will work, but you should not have to reinstall Ubuntu. Brute force would be to reinstall grub. UEFI normally forgets entries when a drive is unplugged. It typically finds Windows, but not Ubuntu in ESP. But you can use efibootmgr to add Ubuntu entry and run `sudo update-grub` to have os-prober add Windows to grub menu. Grub only boots working Windows so make sure fast start up is off (Windows will turn back on with updates). Example efibootmgr entries: https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Also `man efibootmgr`